# How to break one job into two in Github Actions workflow

Tags: firebase, github, yaml, github-actions, cicd

I'm trying to break one job that I have in my workflow into two in Github Actions but can't seem to do so without breaking. I'd like to have build and deploy as two separate jobs if that is possible, so breaking out 'build_and_deploy' and into two jobs i.e like a job1 and job2. Thank you. My code is as follows:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge to Develop
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    name: build_and_deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '15'
      - run: npm ci
      - name: create env file
        env:
          REACT_APP_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_KEY }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID }}
        run: |
         touch .env
         echo REACT_APP_API_KEY="$REACT_APP_API_KEY" >> .env
         echo FAST_REFRESH=false >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID" >> .env
      - run: npm run build
      - name: GitHub Action for Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@v11.22.0
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}


  run_tests:
    name: Run autotests
    needs: build_and_deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: Test Run
        run: |
          curl -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/*****/FootballAppE2ETests/dispatches \
          -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json' \
          -u ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_KEY }} \
          --data '{"event_type": "Trigger Workflow", "client_payload": { "repository": "'"$GITHUB_REPOSITORY"'" }}'
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge to Develop
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '15'
      - run: npm ci
      - name: create env file
        env:
          REACT_APP_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_KEY }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID }}
        run: |
         touch .env
         echo REACT_APP_API_KEY="$REACT_APP_API_KEY" >> .env
         echo FAST_REFRESH=false >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID" >> .env
      - run: npm run build
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: GitHub Action for Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@v11.22.0
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
  run_tests:
    name: Run autotests
    needs: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: Test Run
        run: |
          curl -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/*****/FootballAppE2ETests/dispatches \
          -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json' \
          -u ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_KEY }} \
          --data '{"event_type": "Trigger Workflow", "client_payload": { "repository": "'"$GITHUB_REPOSITORY"'" }}'
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have valid reasons to break your job into multiple ones. Sometimes it's better to run your actions in one job so you don't need to wait for another runner once you finish your job, so your current implementation is fine, you can only improve it by caching npm dependencies.

However, if you still want to, you can follow [the example in w9jds/firebase-action](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action#example) repository, by using [actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) to share your build (`dist`) folder between the `build` and `deployment` jobs:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge to Develop
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build application
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '15'
      - run: npm ci
      - name: create env file
        env:
          REACT_APP_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_KEY }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID }}
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID }}
        run: |
         touch .env
         echo REACT_APP_API_KEY="$REACT_APP_API_KEY" >> .env
         echo FAST_REFRESH=false >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID" >> .env
         echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID="$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID" >> .env
      - run: npm run build
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: dist
          path: dist
  deploy:
    needs: build
    name: Deploy to Firebase
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: dist
          path: dist
      - name: GitHub Action for Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@v11.22.0
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}

  run_tests:
    name: Run autotests
    needs: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: Test Run
        run: |
          curl -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/*****/FootballAppE2ETests/dispatches \
          -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json' \
          -u ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_KEY }} \
          --data '{"event_type": "Trigger Workflow", "client_payload": { "repository": "'"$GITHUB_REPOSITORY"'" }}'
```

Other improvements you may want to consider:

- Upgrade to [`actions/setup-node@v3`](https://github.com/actions/setup-node)
- Upgrade to [`actions/checkout@v3`](https://github.com/actions/checkout)
- [Use cache to speed up your workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows)
- *If you want/can: Upgrade to an [LTS version of Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases)*